# Polymer: using element multiple times with different viewmodel

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, custom-element

I want to create a polymer element and use it in multiple places with different viewModel

polymer element:

```
<polymer-element name="my-elem">
<template>
    <div>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer("my-elem", {
        ready: function() {
            this.firstName = "Souvik";
            this.lastName = "Basu";
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

This works properly and shows name `Souvik Basu` when used in another html page. But instead of hard coding firstName and lastName inside the element, I want to show names of two persons while using this element:

```
<my-elem></my-elem>    // This should show Super Man
<my-elem></my-elem>    // This should show He Man
```

How can I pass JavaScript objects to these elements while using them?

Answer (score 1):

Just make two attributes. You don't event need a script tag for that

```
<my-elem firstName='wir' lastName='lez'></my-elem>

<polymer-element name="my-elem" attributes='firstName lastName' noscript>
    <template><div>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</div></template>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: yes it works for this example, but I had used a simple example for illustrative purpose. My actual case has a complex UI with a complex VM

Comment: If it is really complex use **core-ajax** and a **json-file** hosted by a webserver? PHP can easily do that, mysql could help aswell..

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to set the viewModel, but it is not a clean approach.
Please let me know if you find a better approach that this:

Set an attribute name to be used to set viewModel in attributes of polymer-element. Let's say we add attribute `person`. Then initialize the same attribute in the polymer element prototype as follows:

```
<polymer-element name="my-elem" attributes="person">
<template>
    <div>{{person.firstName}} {{person.lastName}}</div>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer("my-elem", {
        person: {},
        ready: function() {
        }
    });
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Then use like this:

```
<my-elem id="person1" person='{"firstName": "Super", "lastName": "Man"}'></my-elem>
<my-elem id="person2" person='{"firstName": "He", "lastName": "Man"}'></my-elem>
```

If the object is complex, use the JSON.stringify method to store the object in attribute:

```
var el = document.getElementById("person1");
el.setAttribute("person", JSON.stringify({
            "firstName": "Super",
            "lastName": "Man",
        }));
```